# Python - PIP modules that already exist in a venv

Tags: python, pip, package, python-venv

I want to install a few modules - the problem here is, i already have those modules in a virtual enviroment, so i get the
`Requirement already satisfied` error.

How do i avoid this? Is there a way to force PIP to download a package, even if it already exists somewhere on my system? And why does this error even come up when im PIPing *outside* of the venv?
I could paste the modules manually into my normal python folder, but i thought that there has to be a simple method - of course, i could just unmount the entire hard drive where the venv is located on...

Answer (score 1):

a. If you want to reinstall a package you can always uninstall the package and reinstall it with the following.

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests
```

b. If you are seeing "Requirement already satisfied" inside of your vanilla python installation then it must already be installed there. You can check the packages that are installed by running the following. (you can run this on your virtual environment and your vanilla python installation to compare the results)

```
 pip freeze

 defusedxml==0.5.0
 isodate==0.6.0
 lxml==4.2.1
 pkgconfig==1.3.1
 python3-saml==1.4.1
 six==1.11.0
 xmlsec==1.3.3
```

Comment: yes, it says that PyQt5 and jinja are installed - but why am i getting a "no module named "PyQt5"" Error in my vanilla python enviroment >.>? when i run the pyqt script in my venv, it works all well - but i have to be able to use it in vanilla in order to use my IDE

Comment: @FlyingThunder You should be able to point your IDE at your virtual environment.  For example, for all of my projects I use VS Code with a separate virtual environment for each project.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: Thonny  IDE, thinking about going to PyCharm soon

Comment: @FlyingThunder I just started to use VS Code a few months ago and it's my go-to for Python now.  Pycharm is always a good choice too.  Either way, both of these editors should let you point the editor at a python virtualenv.

Comment: alright - thatll do for now, sucks that theres no clean solution for that - thanks anyways

the IDE solved the problem on another way - if i use the Thonny package manager, i can install it just fine!